How to displace a certain number of times a Char in Haskell?
How to displace a Char in Haskell?
I need a code that changes a Char into another displacing a number of times the Char in question.
For example
displace (d: Char, n: Z) : Char
input: d = ’b’, n = 3
output: ’e’
I can only use basic functions. Like ord, &&, ||, ==, :, ++, tail, head, etc. Only the basic ones.

You can use fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int [Hackage] and toEnum :: Enum a => Int -> a [Hackage] to convert to an Int and back:
displace :: Int -> Char -> Char
displace s = toEnum . (s+) . fromEnum


I can not use Higher Order

@Feuergeist, what do you mean by (not) Higher Order? That answer is using only function composition .. And in general, please state in full what exercise you've been given. It feels a lot like you're asking us to do your homework.

Well, I don't understand that code. I need to use basic functions, it seems that we need auxiliary functions.

Did you try the code? Did it work? Composition . is a basic function. Perhaps your lecturer/textbook has a weird idea about what counts as "basic"? Please (for the second time of asking) state exactly what question you've been given.

the answer given is just a more compact way of writing displace s c = toEnum (fromEnum c + s), which has nothing "higher order" in sight.
